# How to echo a wordpress value inside an 'echo'

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo, href

I'm trying to do this:

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<span class="ciao">HELLO ' . $current_user->user_login . '</span>'; "\n"; 
    echo '<a href=" . wp_logout_url( home_url() ); . " title="Logout">Logout</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href=" . wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); . " title="Login">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

The problem is that href gives me back the empty value:  **wp_logout_url( home_url() );**

When I use this WORDPRESS call outside the echo it **works good**, like this eg:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">LOGOUT</a>
```

How can i write this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those was, but I appreciated. 
This works well:

```
'<a href="'.wp_logout_url( home_url() ).'">text</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url() ) . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
```

Comment: i had already wrote that, but was'n correct! by the way I've found (with no white spaces!!)

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<a href=" . wp_logout_url( home_url() ); . " title="Logout">Logout</a>';`

Needs to be changed to

`echo '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url() ) . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';`

String started with single quote needs to be closed with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
<?php global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<span class="ciao">HELLO ' . $current_user->user_login . '</span>'; "\n"; 
echo '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url() ); . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); . '" title="Login">Login</a>'; } ?>
```

The different is the string is closed before the result of wp_logout_url() is concatenated with it

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've not ended you string

You'd want to use the following:

```
echo "<a href=\"" . wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); . "\"/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct option

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
echo '<span class="ciao">HELLO ' . $current_user->user_login . '</span>\n';
echo '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url() ) . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>'; 
} else {
echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) . '" title="Login">Login</a>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English website - please amend your answer to provide an explanation in English.